# Trigger an event in nginx when a connection to RTMP module is made or dropped

Tags: events, nginx, connection, rtmp

I use nginx RTMP module to broadcast video streams. The data is pushed to the nginx/RTMP server from remote devices which are hooked via 3G connections, where we pay per MB transferred, so it is in my interest to stream video into the server only when there are listeners/players.

(Unfortunately, for those not familiar with RTMP, the server is always "swallowing" data even if there are no listeners to watch the live stream).

I have found a way to start streaming into the nginx/RTMP server, so I can conserve the data across 3G (simple redirect of web link to rtmp link, no problem), but I cannot find any reliable way to detect when the RTMP client (player) closes a connection, to stop the devices from streaming into nginx.

So my question is: is there a way to instruct nginx (or its RTMP module) to trigger an event, a signal, create/delete a file when a connection to particular RTMP URL is made? I could live by observing creation/deletion of files, via incron, so that would be quite ok.

Or do I need to go to API level or even deeper into the source?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you got an answer for this already. Either way I would suggest looking headers like **exec_publish, exec_record_done, on_play and on_publish** events in directives of https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives

**on_publish** might help to check the status and allow or reject stream

Comment: Difference between on_publish and on_play ?